# How do I figure out what is blocking port 80?

Tags: debian, networking, apache-httpd, firewall, wget

We are running Apache on a Debian 8 box, which is behind a router.  I can tell Apache is running and serving pages because when I log in to the box, I'm able to wget the web page, using both the "localhost" address and the local IP, shown by an "ifconfig" command

```
myuser@myserver:~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:37:ae:d2:3f:29
          inet addr:192.168.0.114  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d964:f94e:233d:6f55/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:103604 errors:0 dropped:20 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:54463 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:33144049 (31.6 MiB)  TX bytes:6391213 (6.0 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9550967 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9550967 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:1519312520 (1.4 GiB)  TX bytes:1519312520 (1.4 GiB)
```

and here I can "wget" the page, by going to the terminal of the machine itself

```
myuser@myserver:~ $ wget http://192.168.0.114
converted 'http://192.168.0.114' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'http://192.168.0.114' (UTF-8)
--2017-09-18 14:54:01--  http://192.168.0.114/
Connecting to 192.168.0.114:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html.2'

index.html.2                                           [ <=>                                                                                                               ]   7.33K  --.-KB/s   in 0s

2017-09-18 14:54:06 (31.8 MB/s) - 'index.html.2' saved [7506]
```

But when we visit http://192.168.0.114 on a web browser within the LAN, we don't get any response.  I'm trying to figure out what else could be blocking the connection.  I'm assuming if we try and access via the local IP, we are bypassing the router at this stage.

Comment: Can you reach port 80 from any machine on the LAN? If not, then it may well be the firewall on the webserver...

Comment: @Christopher, et al, how do I do that?

Comment: Check to see if the firewall is even active and doing anything - `iptables -L`